# chart.js plot timeseries data on a fixed timescale

Tags: javascript, typescript, charts, ng2-charts

I've got a data with the interval of 1 minutes for `steppedLine` chart which is looks like:

```
0: {x: "15:33", y: 0}
1: {x: "15:34", y: 0}
2: {x: "15:35", y: 1}
3: {x: "15:36", y: 1}
4: {x: "15:37", y: 0}
```

The data however might only cover few hours from 24 hours(no data available for remained hours) I want to plot it on the 24 hour hour scale 

  `public lineChartLabels: Array<any> = ['0:00', '1:00', '2:00', '3:00', '4:00', '5:00', '6:00', '7:00', '8:00', '9:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00', '18:00', '19:00', '20:00', '21:00', '22:00', '23:00'];`

**Question** - what is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You could add in the other fields for the 24 hours, but keep them blank and overwrite them as time goes on.

(I would comment this, but I don't have enough reputation.)